# Comment out lines between two different patterns within a file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I want to insert a "#" at the beginning of each line within a file. But only to those lines between a section:

```
################## PATTERN #1 ##############
blah 1243234
blah asdfsyxfvb
blah asdfasdfg
################## PATTERN #2 ##############
```

-->

```
################## PATTERN #1 ##############
#blah 1243234
#blah asdfsyxfvb
#blah asdfasdfg
################## PATTERN #2 ##############
```

I got it almost with my limited knowledge about awk and sed. But I'm struggling to merge the output into my file.

```
awk '/################## PATTERN #1/{flag=1;next}/################## PATTERN #2/{flag=0}flag' myinputfile | sed 's/^/#/'
```

Thanks in advance for helping me out.

*P. S. As I'm new here: If someone has an idea for a better title/tags please let me know and I will change it.*

Comment: What should happen if the "pattern 1" line exists but the "pattern 2" line doesn't? Should lines til the end of file be commented out or no lines commented out or something else?

Comment: Both patterns are always present. Both solutions are working flawlessly. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
$ awk '/PATTERN #2/{f=0} f{$0="#" $0} /PATTERN #1/{f=1} 1' file
################## PATTERN #1 ##############
#blah 1243234
#blah asdfsyxfvb
#blah asdfasdfg
################## PATTERN #2 ##############
```

Obviously adjust the "pattern" delimiters to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the second pattern always exists, a `sed` one-liner might do the job:

```
sed '/PATTERN #1/,/PATTERN #2/s/^/#/' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code might be reworked to do what you wants. Lets `file.txt` content be

```
################## PATTERN #1 ##############
blah 1243234
blah asdfsyxfvb
blah asdfasdfg
################## PATTERN #2 ##############
```

then

```
awk '/################## PATTERN #1/{flag=1;print;next}/################## PATTERN #2/{flag=0;print;next}{print (flag?"#":"") $0}' file.txt
```

output

```
################## PATTERN #1 ##############
#blah 1243234
#blah asdfsyxfvb
#blah asdfasdfg
################## PATTERN #2 ##############
```

Explanation: for line with `PATTERN #1` set flag to 0, print line, go to next line, for line with `PATTERN #2` set flag to 1, print line, go to next line, for every other line if flag is true (1) then prepend line with `#` and print, if flag is false (0) then prepend line with empty string (i.e. do not change) and print. I used ternary operator (condition`?`valueiftrue`:`valueiffalse) to select string suitable to flag value

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/PATTERN #1/{:a;N;/PATTERN #2/!ba;s/^[^#]\?/#&/mg}' file
```

Gather up lines between `PATTERN #1` and `PATTERN #2` and insert `#` at the front of lines that do not have them.

N.B. This will only update a file if **both** patterns are present.

---

To amend the least lines between `PATTERN #1` and `PATTERN #2` i.e. `PATTERN #1` occurs again before `PATTERN #2` the lines from the first occurrence of `PATTERN #1` will not be commented, use:

```
 sed '/PATTERN #1/{:a;N;/\n.*PATTERN #1/{h;s/\(.*\)\n.*/\1/p;g;s/.*\n//;ba}
      /PATTERN #2/!ba;s/^[^#]\?/#&/mg}' file
```